# Authorization ssh with plink from windows command line

Tags: git, putty

I'm trying to connect and fetching source from a SSH server with using PuTTY, PLINK and git from command line. When connecting with PuTTY or Git Extension/TortoiseGit/etc. There is no trouble. I can login or fetch/upload files.

**Set variables and Executed plink**

```
GIT_SSH={somePath}\plink.exe

plink -i key.ppk -ssh ssh://user@server:port
```

and getting following error:

```
FATAL ERROR : Network error: Connection Refused
```

Comment: This sounds more like the remote end doesn't accept SSH connections on that port ... maybe another port, maybe another host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plink -i key.ppk -ssh user@server -P port -l user
```

Comment: its not a big deal, but the username twice is redundant. should be fine with one or the other.

Comment: where to get key.ppk